# DataRow Parameter Generation with for loop in C# Test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parameters

I am trying to write some tests for C# methods. A example is like as below.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(1, 1)]
[DataRow(2, 1)]
[DataRow(3, 1)]
[DataRow(1, 2)]
[DataRow(2, 2)]
[DataRow(3, 2)]
[DataRow(1, 3)]
[DataRow(2, 3)]
[DataRow(3, 3)]
public void TestMethod1(int value1, int value2)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(value1.ToString() + value2.ToString(), string.Concat(value1.ToString(), value2.ToString()));
}
```

I'm wondering that is there any syntax support to generate multiple DataRows with for-loop?

```
[DataTestMethod]
[for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++){ DataRow(j, i) }}] // Something like this
public void TestMethod1(int value1, int value2)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(value1.ToString() + value2.ToString(), string.Concat(value1.ToString(), value2.ToString()));
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps consider using data-driven tests via `[DataSource]`  and an external data source like an .xlsx file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way with using DynamicData. The main purpose of static method "TestCaseGenerator" is to construct the for-loops structure for generating test cases. Actually, the test cases are created one-by-one with `yield return` syntax. Across the board, the functionality of this "TestCaseGenerator" method is similar to the requirement of `[for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++){ DataRow(j, i) }}] // Something like this` in the question.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestCaseGenerator), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void TestMethod1(int value1, int value2)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(value1.ToString() + value2.ToString(), string.Concat(value1.ToString(), value2.ToString()));
}
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]> TestCaseGenerator()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            yield return new object[] { j, i };
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for the notification, I already update the content.